# How to parametrize the boundary curve by Stokes' theorem in general form with example?

Tags: parametrization, stokes-theorem

Can we parametrize the boundary curve of parametrized surface and is there a specific method?. I'm trying to using Stokes' theorem.
For any parametrized surface.
$$
r(u,v)=\langle f(u,v),g(u,v),h(u,v)\rangle
$$

Comment: You need to think about the region in $(u,v)$-space that parametrizes your surface, of course. Then look at its boundary curve.

Comment: How? @TedShifrin

Comment: Well, what region parametrizes your surface?

Comment: The boundary of region is intersection with $\langle\frac{ru}{2\pi}\cos(v),\frac{ru} {2\pi}\sin(v),0\rangle$, where $u,v$ from $0$ to $2\pi$. @TedShifrin

Comment: This does not make sense. The region in the $(u,v)$-plane is apparently the square given by $0\le u,v\le 2\pi$. It might be good to draw where the boundary of that square maps in $3$-space.

Comment: Yes, but the boundary curve is an intersection between $\langle \frac{ru}{2pi}\cos(v),\frac{ru}{2pi}\sin(v),0\rangle$ and $\langle f(u,v),g(u,v),h(u,v)\rangle$. That is what I wanted to say. @TedShifrin

Comment: This continues to make no sense. Edit your post to include the precise question.

Comment: Just take the four curves $$\gamma(t)=\begin{cases}r(a,t)\\r(b,t)\\r(t,c)\\r(t,d)\end{cases}$$ Or do you want these spliced together as a single curve?

Comment: @mr_e_man Properly oriented, of course. Draw the rectangle and orient its boundary (usually counterclockwise).